# how to make tuple as HEAP_XMAX_COMMITTED

Tags: postgresql

I am not sure what does HEAP_XMAX_COMMITTED correspond to what kind of real situation.
there is no test case in [1] about HEAP_XMAX_COMMITTED.

two session, how to reproduce case where tuple flags as HEAP_XMAX_COMMITTED?

---

another part IN src/backend/access/heap/README.tuplock

> We currently never set the HEAP_XMAX_COMMITTED when the
> HEAP_XMAX_IS_MULTI bit is set.

[1] https://git.postgresql.org/cgit/postgresql.git/plain/contrib/pageinspect/expected/page.out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HEAP_XMAX_COMMITTED` is a hint bit that says that the row was deleted or updated (which sets `xmax`), and the transaction that did that has committed.

Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE seeme (id integer);

INSERT INTO seeme VALUES (1);

UPDATE seeme SET id = 2;

SELECT p.lp, p.t_ctid, p.t_xmin, p.t_xmax, i.*, p.t_attrs
FROM heap_page_item_attrs(get_raw_page('seeme', 0), 'seeme') AS p
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL heap_tuple_infomask_flags(p.t_infomask, p.t_infomask2) AS i;

 lp │ t_ctid │  t_xmin  │  t_xmax  │                    raw_flags                     │ combined_flags │     t_attrs     
════╪════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════╪════════════════╪═════════════════
  1 │ (0,2)  │ 10004716 │ 10004717 │ {HEAP_XMIN_COMMITTED,HEAP_HOT_UPDATED}           │ {}             │ {"\\x01000000"}
  2 │ (0,2)  │ 10004717 │        0 │ {HEAP_XMAX_INVALID,HEAP_UPDATED,HEAP_ONLY_TUPLE} │ {}             │ {"\\x02000000"}
(2 rows)
```

The first row with line pointer 1 has been updated (`xmax` is not 0), but nobody has read that row yet, so the hint bit is not set.

Along comes the first reader:

```
SELECT * FROM seeme;

 id 
════
  2
(1 row)

SELECT p.lp, p.t_ctid, p.t_xmin, p.t_xmax, i.*, p.t_attrs
FROM heap_page_item_attrs(get_raw_page('seeme', 0), 'seeme') AS p
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL heap_tuple_infomask_flags(p.t_infomask, p.t_infomask2) AS i;

 lp │ t_ctid │  t_xmin  │  t_xmax  │                              raw_flags                               │ combined_flags │     t_attrs     
════╪════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╪════════════════╪═════════════════
  1 │ (0,2)  │ 10004716 │ 10004717 │ {HEAP_XMIN_COMMITTED,HEAP_XMAX_COMMITTED,HEAP_HOT_UPDATED}           │ {}             │ {"\\x01000000"}
  2 │ (0,2)  │ 10004717 │        0 │ {HEAP_XMIN_COMMITTED,HEAP_XMAX_INVALID,HEAP_UPDATED,HEAP_ONLY_TUPLE} │ {}             │ {"\\x02000000"}
(2 rows)
```

Now the hint bit is set, and the next reader doesn't have to consult the commit log to find out if the tuple with line pointer 1 is visible or not.